# I am trying to create a portfolio website using html, but there is some unknown space created which I cannot seem to understand why

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="banner-img-div brdr">
    <div class="bg-black fnt-white visualize-brdr inline-block banner-text brdr" id="banner-text">
        <p class="fnt-white inline-block intro-p hover-orange">
            Hi, I am Blank
        </p>
        <h1 class="hover-orange"> Aspiring Software Progr<span>Ammer</span></h1>

        <h3 class="roboto hover-orange">
            Currently pursuing an undergraduate Bachelor's degree at the <span>University of Blank</span>
        </h3>

        <div class="bg-orange inline-block roboto text-center resume-container">
            <a href="#" class="margin-auto roboto resume" style="font-size: 20px;">RESUME</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <img class="banner-img brdr" src="./Images/man-black-bg.jpg" alt="manworking" width="inherit">
</div>

<div id="Project" class="bg-white fnt-white brdr project-div">
    <div class="inline-block image-for-project-container brdr">
        <img src="./Images/manworking.webp" alt="manworking" height="630px">
    </div>

    <div class=" project-container inline-block">
        <h2 class="text-center fnt-black head-portfolio">
            Lorem, ipsum.
        </h2>
        <br>
        <br>
        <p class="margin-auto txt-portfolio roboto hover-orange fnt-black">
            Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vero nemo dolore sit perferendis qui ad hic,
            expedita, magnam ipsam est eligendi nulla,
        </p>
        <br>
        <a href="#" class="buttons read-more fnt-black">Read More</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

The Above was my HTML code.

My relevant CSS:

```
.project-container{
    height: 500px;
    width: 300px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    /* border: 1px solid rgb(63, 61, 61); */
    transition: all 0.5s;
    border-radius: 10px;
    
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    margin-top: 0px; 
}

.project-div{
    padding-left:  10px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding-top: 0px;
}

.banner-img-div{
    height: auto;
    /* border: red solid; */
    background: url(./Images/leaf-black-background.webp);
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.image-for-project-container{
    margin-top: 40px;

}
```

These are all the classes which do involve margin/padding hence why I called them relevant. I am a beginner in HTML hence there is a slight chance I missed out on something so please help me so.

My issue is

As you can see there is large gap of space between the Lorem Ipsum container and the div. How do I solve this? Any and all thoughts will be greatly appreciated !. Thanks (the imgur link if it doesn't show :  https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpbSo.png )

Comment: Have you inspected your elements using chrome dev tools?

Comment: @Sadeed_pv I have. It is showing that there is no element in that blank space.

Comment: Try using css floats. Basically that image and content on left should be `float :left`', unless its a flexbox, grid.

Comment: @pixlboy it works, thanks. But suppose i made multiple lorem ipsum containers, then when there is a certain number they will start on a new line, how do I make it so that the new line starts at the same beginning of the image? I hope you do understand my question.

Comment: I did not understand your question.

Maybe it would be nice to change the image example to a working example in stack overflow. using insert code feature.

Answer (score 0):

The '.project-container' class in your css file has a padding-bottom of 50px and margin-bottom of 30px;
Maybe try changing that.

```
    .project-container{
        height: 500px;
        width: 300px;    
        -> padding-bottom: 50px
        -> margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately, it does not work. It only decreases the space underneath the lorem ipsum container (project-container).